# Changing the results of a regex capture group to lowercase in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this regex capture group:

```
$lowerPattern='(href[\s]?=[\s]?\"[^"]*[^"]*\")'
```

which is returning all the matches I need just fine.  However I need to replace the capture group with the results all lowercase:

```
$lowerPatternReplace = '$1'.ToLower()
```

This doesn't seem to be working. How you lowercase a capture group in powershell regex?

Comment: The repeated pattern `[^"]*` in your RE doesn't make sense to me, the 1st one will greedily get all none `"` chars and the 2nd will be empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code seems to work for me. It's just a bit less shorthand. I didn't see a way to do it with backreferences, due to the order of execution (you're lowering the literal string '$1').

```
$Entry = 'asdHREFasd'
$RegEx = '(href)'
$match = $Entry -match $RegEx
[string]$upper = $Matches[1] #first capture group
[string]$lower = $upper.ToLower()
[string]$Entry.replace($upper,$lower)
```

[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/73teo5/replace_parts_of_string_to_lowercase/dnsyrtm/)

Comment: `$Entry = 'asdHREFasd'; $RegEx = '(href)'; if($Entry -match $RegEx){$Entry = $Entry.Replace($Matches[1],$Matches[1].ToLower())}`

Comment: Fixed it with this.  Thanks.  Looks like the $Matches was the key.